# Power/Mockito ignoring reference update

Tags: java, junit, mockito, pass-by-reference, powermock

I've got following class

```
import com.model.domain.Node;

public class Linker {
    public void link(Node node){
        node = Node.findById(node.getId());

        if(node.getLinkedNode() == null)
            return;
    }
}
```

and unit test for it

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import com.model.domain.Node;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Node.class})
public class LinkerTest {

    private Linker linker = new Linker();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Node.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLink() throws Exception {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.setId(123456L);

        Node foundNode = new Node();
        foundNode.setId(1234L);
        foundNode.setName("FounNode");

        when(Node.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(foundNode);

        linker.link(node);

        assertEquals(node, foundNode);
    }
}
```

now, my problem is that in the testLink test, I would expect object `node`s reference to point to `foundNode` object after line `linker.link(node);` is executed as link method changes the reference to the object.

However, that is not the case. in the `Linker#link` method the reference is correctly updated but after the return in `LinkerTest#testLink` method the reference is still the original one and the assertion fails.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You know that Java only [passes by value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1426891), right? You can pass references to objects, and those objects may be modified in the method, but the variable at the call site will never _refer to a different instance_ due only to a method call.

Comment: Thanks for the wake up call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java only [passes by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1426891). You can pass references to objects, and those objects may be modified in the method, but the variable at the call site will never refer to a different instance due only to a method call.

One way around this is to pass in an object that wraps a reference:

```
class Holder {
  Node node;
}
```

...so the reference to Holder stays constant but the field it contains may change. If possible, though, prefer to *return a value* rather than *mutating state*, which will likely also make your class easier to test.